# IIS Windows Authentication not asking for credentials

Tags: windows, iis-7, windows-authentication

I am trying to set up a new web site using IIS7 on Windows 2008R2
The instructions i am using say to enabled Windows Authentication as seen below:

[image: Auth]

The instruction say that when i try and request a page from the new site I should be prompted with a dialogue box that asks for credentials.  But, when I request the page it shows up without a prompt.  I tried both Explorer and Chrome and neither prompted for credentials.

What steps am i missing?

Comment: Are you logged in as a authenticated user on your Windows client?

Comment: Yes I am logged in as a authenticated user on your Windows

Comment: Then your cached Windows credentials are being used (if there is no error). If you absolutely MUST have a login form, you have to use Basic Authentication, for example.

Comment: Yeah. That is the mai nreason to use windows authentication - in a domain, people are never asked, login is transparent.

Comment: If your machine and the server are joined to the same AD domain then you won't be prompted for authentication when accessing the site. Your browser authenticates "transparently" to the server using your credentials. If your machine and the server were not joined to the same AD domain then you would be prompted for credentials, but only after your browser first attempted to authenticate with your credentials.